# Set Task list EnableAssignToEmail in CSOM

Tags: 2013, list, sharepoint-online, client-object-model

I would like to set the EnableAssignToEmail bit on a task list via CSOM after a list is created dynamically. I have found a way to do this in Powershell and in code using SPList:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell

$web = Get-SPWeb "http://foo/web"
$list = $web.Lists.TryGetList("Tasks")

$list.EnableAssignToEmail = $true
$list.Update()
```

I do not see a specific method or property on SP.List in the CSOM SP.List API: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245826(v=office.15).aspx#constructors.

Is there some trick to get this enabled, or is it just not possible?

Comment: See https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/982a68ee-c5cc-41fc-ad12-eb2e5ecfb578/how-to-disable-the-alerts-at-itemlistsite-level-using-ecma-or-sp-services-in-sharepoint-2010?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious

Comment: @Ankur, that is for 2010, and really does not answer the question about if there is a workaround in 2013 as of today (specifically since the question is tagged with SharePoint Online, making writing your own web service impossible)

Comment: @RobertLindgren This is already a request in uservoice pending since last year March. https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/suggestions/7402411-enableassigntoemail-list-method-missing-on-list-ob

Comment: @akhoy, I know, hence I look for a work around :)

Comment: @RobertLindgren Are you ok to use designer workflows?

Comment: @AsadRefai that would be a possible (if yet tricky) workaround I suppose :)

Comment: Can i get the powershell code for export the task list which is enabled EnableAssignToEmail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shall work with a new CSOM Version:
https://dev.office.com/blogs/new-sharepoint-csom-version-released-for-Office-365-august-2016-updated

Answer (score 2):

Reflector shows us that `EnableAssignToEmail` is not decorated with the [ClientCallable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.clientcallableattribute.aspx) attribute, thus is not accessible via CSOM.

Comment: The real question is, is there another way of setting it (since it clearly is not available as a property of the list directly)?

Comment: ...which is why there is a UV to request it, since there is not a method to set it.

Comment: Not everything is gettable/settable in SPO via CSOM or PS compared to on prem, it's frustrating at times but 'tis the nature of a hosted service offering.

Comment: Truly that's the case. Have seen some nice workarounds for setting stuff not really exposed before though (like Available page layouts etc.), so figured it was worth a shot to ask for an alternate way